# How can I disable Hibernate-cache logs?

Tags: hibernate, grails, log4j

My Grails app log is being flooded with thousands of messages like:

```
2010-05-21 18:54:08,261 [30462143@qtp-19943008-38] DEBUG hibernate.EhCache  - key: ga_event value: 5220206380077056
```

This is my log4j config:

```
// log4j configuration
log4j = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console
    // appender:
    //
    appenders {
        console name:'stdout',layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
        rollingFile name:'applog', file: logDirectory+"/${appName}_main.log", maxFileSize:'10MB'
        //'null' name:'stacktrace'
        file name: 'stacktrace', file: logDirectory+"/${appName}_stacktrace.log", layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    }

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           stacktrace: "stacktrace"

    warn   'org.mortbay.log'

    root {
        debug 'stdout', 'applog'
        additivity = true
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to disable that log?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding into the error block `net.sf.ehcache`